# Used cloud-flare on a site, but an error occurs (link wrong or retired)

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, cloudflare, forwarding

I am trying to point the domain www.xxx.com to www.ttio.com/tc using cloudflare to enable to the https on the site.

1. On GoDaddy I have changed the nameservers to cloudflare's recommended name servers
2. I have also gone to "Page rules" on Cloudflare and added a forwarding rule so that the above is in place.

On going to www.xxx.com however, i get the following error:

It redirects to this url: **https://shortener.secureserver.net/error_404**
and the error is:

```
Destination
Unknown

Everything's working on our side, so the link you clicked is either wrong or has been retired.
```

I have done everything I think I should have, so could anyone shed any light on this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't point a domain (e.g. www.xxx.com) at an URL (e.g. www.ttio.com/tc). A domain needs to be converted to an IP address by the browser.

If the web server for www.ttio.com is set to recognise www.xxx.com and serve the content from the /tc folder under www.ttio.com, just set up a CNAME for www.xxx.com pointing www.ttio.com and it will work.

If the web server for www.ttio.com doesn't know about www.xxx.com at all, you'll need to use a translation proxy. One way of doing that is using a Cloudflare worker to map the www.xxx.com/PATH URL to www.ttio.com/tc/PATH. An example of how to do this is at https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/tutorials/configure-your-cdn/. You may also need to rewrite the HTML so that links in the pages don't point to www.ttio.com/tc. An example of how to do that is at https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/reference/apis/html-rewriter/.